# Firebase deploy issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am learning web development. At now I'm practicing some react projects with firebase authentication. But after finishing the deployment, I'm only getting this(image mentioned)[here image says "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully set up Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!"][1] But I was supposed to get the project output in the browser.
I followed every steps of firebase Hosting. Maybe I missed something.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5iqk.png

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed the App via`> firebase deploy` in the console, there should be a URL mentioned in the console pointing to the active website.